# How to pass data from xamarin form to webpage?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, appium

I'm new to xamarin, and I have being assign to do a simple facebook login system for my school project.

I have my xamarin form interface, which contain user ID text box and password textbook together with the login button, after user key in the ID(email) and password it will direct pass the data to facebook webpage and login automatically, I try to apply selenium but the package was fail to downloa, I try also the appium after get some advice from expert but i face the same problem also that appium package not able download for xamarin android portable form, so any idea suggested about this issue? Thanks

Comment: Could you use Facebook API directly instead of create a login page yourself? Example: https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Facebook-Login-Xamarin-Forms

Comment: This is the tutorial video: https://youtu.be/xGW9Q4atJNc

Comment: @Janson , hello, I dont  Facebook API, is it compulsory require the Facebook API?   Because the requirement of this project is apply selenium method

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about Selenium.but it seem like a automating web application testing tool for UITest or Unit Test.

Comment: @Janson hi , any materials can share me regarding the Unit Test that able to do authentication on the login page?